# Scrapyd can't find the code in a sub-directory

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

We have a quite normal Scrapy project, something like that:

```
project/
       setup.py
       scrapy.cfg
       SOME_DIR_WITH_PYTHON_MODULE/
                                  __init__.py
       project/
              settings.py
              pipelines.py
              __init__.py
              spiders/
                     __init__.py
                     somespider.py
```

Everything works great if we run it from command line `scrapy crawl somespider...`

But when we deploy it and run using Scrapyd, it just fails to import the code from SOME_DIR_WITH_PYTHON_MODULE. Looks like it doesn't see the code there for some unknown reasons.

We tried to import it in the pipelines.py file. Tried like that:

`from project.SOME_DIR_WITH_PYTHON_MODULE import *`

and like that:

`from SOME_DIR_WITH_PYTHON_MODULE import *`

...and nothing worked. Though it worked if ran from command-line 'direct' execution using scrapy crawl.

What should we do to make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I found the reason. I should've used **data_files** param:

```
setup(
    name='blabla',
    version='1.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    entry_points={'scrapy': ['settings = blabla.settings']},
    zip_safe=False,
    include_package_data=True,
    data_files=[(root, [os.path.join(root, f) for f in files])
         for root, _, files in itertools.chain(os.walk('monitoring'),
                                               os.walk('blabla/data'))],
    install_requires=[
        "Scrapy>=0.22",
    ],
    extras_require={
        'Somemodule': ["numpy"],
    }
)
```

That's a bit weird because the code is the data, actually... but it worked for us.

Thanks for the attention. Solved.